Why are contour integrals in the upper and lower half plane equal?
Take a complex function:
$$\phi(t)=\frac{1}{\prod_j \left(1-2i w_j t \right)^{k_j/2}},$$
where the $w_j$ are both positive and negative. So it has purely imaginary poles $t=\frac{-i}{2w_j}$ in both the positive and negative imaginary axis.
Now say we have to take its Fourier transform:
$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} \phi(t) e^{-itx} dt $$
If we do a contour integral on a semicircle that closes in the lower half plane, it only sums the residues over the lower poles (calculable using Cauchy's integral formula). But closing the semicircle in the upper half plane sums the residues over the upper poles. But in both cases, as the arc part goes to infinity, its contribution goes to zero (or does it), and the result is just the integration over the real line.
That means that the residues across the upper poles should sum to the same value as across the lower poles. That does not seem obvious, looking at the function. How can we prove that for this function, or is my statement wrong due to some mistake, eg that the contribution of the arc does not go to 0 in some case?

What is $k_j$?  Unless $k_j$ is an even integer.  There are branchpoint singularities for which one needs to account.
